# Black screen on boot, no xorg error messages

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, gnome, nvidia, hybrid-graphics

I recently installed bumblebee in order to use my discrete graphics card instead of the Intel integrated one. Now I'm left with a machine booting into a black screen. I unmistakeable bumblebee again but that did no good.

The weird thing is that there are no errors in that log file.

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23259719/)

[/etc/X11/xorg.conf](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23259747/)

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Logs seem to sugget a notebook? Do you see something after pressing CTR+ALT+F1?

Answer (score 0):

Please rename your Xorg.conf. Bumblebee has his own xorg.config, in /etc/bumblebee/ as far as I know named `xorg.conf.nvidia` 
So you overwrite it.
Have you edit the  `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` ?

```
Driver=nvidia
[…]
## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-xxx
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-xxx:/usr/lib32/nvidia-xxx
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-xxx/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
```

For the xxx you mußt write the instalt Version.

Example (352 oder 340-updates)

Reboot. I hope I could explain it well and it works.

Source is a german Wiki for Ubuntu.